# Kotlin parcelize issue with gson

Tags: kotlin, gson, parcelable, json-deserialization

I am using @parcelize for gson

Here is my class

```
@Parcelize
data class CommunityModel(@SerializedName("post") val post: PostModel,
                                   @SerializedName("is_liked") val isLiked: Boolean,
                                   @SerializedName("post_like") val postLike: QuestionModel,
                                   @SerializedName("polling_options") val pollingOptions: List<PollingModel>,
                                   @SerializedName("post_polled") val postPolled: Boolean) : Parcelable
```

I got error `Unable to invoke no-args constructor for class. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.`.

But this error only presents on **older android versions** (below 5.0)

I tried implementing default constructor :

```
constructor: this(PostModel(), true, QuestionModel(), emptyList(), true)
```

But it gave me `java.lang.VerifyError` instead

I am using retrofit2 with rxjava2 and gson converter Version **2.3**

My kotlin version is **1.1.51**

Is it known bug? Or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**No-arg compiler plugin**

The no-arg compiler plugin generates an additional zero-argument constructor for classes with a specific annotation.

The generated constructor is synthetic so it can’t be directly called from Java or Kotlin, but it can be called using reflection.

This allows the Java Persistence API (JPA) to instantiate the data class although it doesn't have the zero-parameter constructor from Kotlin or Java point of view (see the description of kotlin-jpa plugin below).

Using in Gradle

The usage is pretty similar to all-open.

Add the plugin and specify the list of annotations that must lead to generating a no-arg constructor for the annotated classes.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin-noarg"
```

Source https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html

Comment: can you give me example on how to use it? I tried the link above, and still does not work.